# ExtJS and GoJS integration (tabpanel)

Tags: extjs, gojs

I'm building a diagram app using GoJS library and ExtJS.

The GoJS needs to be renderer to a div.

```
<div id="myDiagram" class="diagramStyle"></div>
```

And I want to grab this div and insert it into a panel (tab panel):

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'border',
        items: [
            {
                region: 'north',
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                padding: '5px',
                height: 45,
                items: [
                    'MyApp'
                ]
            },
            {
                region: 'center',
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                margin: '5px',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtyope: 'panel',
                        title: 'panel1',
                        contentEl: Ext.get(myDiagram)
                    },
                    {
                        xtyope: 'panel',
                        title: 'panel2'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

But this approach didn't work, I'm getting some errors when I click over the diagram to edit it.

```
   window.MSGesture && (a.po = new window.MSGesture, a.po.target = b, b.addEventListener("pointerdown", function(b) {
        a.po.addPointer(b.pointerId)
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Or there is a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```js
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'border',
        items: [
            {
                region: 'north',
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                padding: '5px',
                height: 45,
                items: [
                    'MyApp'
                ]
            },
            {
                region: 'center',
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                margin: '5px',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: 'panel1',
                        html: '<div id="myDiagram" class="diagramStyle"></div>'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: 'panel2'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });

    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
    var myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "myDiagram", {
      // properties...
    });
});
```

Note the html property at panel